# Testing for different possibilities of a $_Get form value

Tags: php

Php newbie... Tried searching but not couldn't find anything...what am I doing wrong here?

The first `if` statement is calculating as `true` even when`$_GET['Submit']=="Other Choice"`.

I need it to calculate as `false.`  The first `if` should calculate `true` only when  `$_Get[
'Submit']` equals `yes` or `maybe` or `no`, but not `Other Choice`.

When it equals "Other Choice" the second if statement should return true (which it does).

Thanks for advice!

form.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['Submit']) && ($_GET['Submit'] == ('Yes'||'Maybe'||'No')) )
{
$choice=$_GET['Submit'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Submit']) && ($_GET['Submit'] == ('Other Choice')) )
{
$choice=$_GET['Submit'];
}
?>

<form action="form.php" method="get" name="Submit" id="Submit">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Yes" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Maybe" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="No" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Other Choice" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`||` in programming is not like `or` in English, you can't put them together like that. You have to write:

```
if (isset($_GET['Submit'])
          && ($_GET['Submit'] == 'Yes' || $_GET['Submit'] == 'Maybe' || $_GET['Submit'] == 'No')) )
```

or:

```
if (isset($_GET['Submit']) && in_array($_GET['Submit'], array('Yes'||'Maybe'||'No')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Submit']) && ($_GET['Submit']=='Yes'|| $_GET['Submit']=='Maybe'|| $_GET['Submit']=='No'))
{
    $choice=$_GET['Submit'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Submit']) && ($_GET['Submit'] == 'Other Choice'))
{
    $choice=$_GET['Submit'];
}
?>
```